# CreateProcess и принудительный вызов TerminateProcess

Tags: delphi

Некоторые инсталляторы при установке завершают работу перезагрузкой системы. Иногда, при установке по списку, нужно отложить этот шаг. Решение вижу в применении флага типа Boolean, который в CreateProcess вызовет TerminateProcess(..). Правильным ли будет такое решение?

```
  if not CreateProcess(nil, PChar(CmdLine), nil, nil, false,
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, WorkingDir, StartupInfo, ProcessInfo) then
  begin
    Result := false;
    ErrorCode := GetLastError;
    Exit;
  end;

  with ProcessInfo do
  begin
    CloseHandle(hThread);

    if WaitUntilIdle then
      WaitForInputIdle(hProcess, INFINITE); // ожидание инициализации
    if WaitUntilTerminated then // ожидание завершения процесса
    repeat
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      until MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, hProcess, false, INFINITE, 
        QS_ALLINPUT) <> WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1;
    if Flag = False then 
      CloseHandle(hProcess)
    else
      TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0)
```

Comment: Насильственное прерывание - это всегда плохо. Однако, если Вы уверены, что прерываете процесс инсталлятора уже на шаге "всё готово, хотите ли по завершению прочитать Release notes" - то (если инсталлятор сделан правильно) ничего страшного не случится.

Comment: Я бы советовал сначала попробовать запустить инсталлятор с ключом `/?` или поискать описание его в интернете. Т.к. очень многие инсталляторы имеют ключ командной строки для отложенной перезагрузки, даже если в самом процессе установки такая возможность не предусмотрена.

Comment: @Alekcvp Спасибо! Это само собой, но бывают и исключения, при этом, вся логика установки по списку ломается.

Comment: @kami Спасибо! Я понимаю, но другого пути, пока не нашел. Проверять ключ в HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\InProgress, тоже не надежно, он может удаляться асинхронно с началом процесса перезагрузки. А ловить и убивать процесс по имени или ID, сразу по завершению "успешной" установки, практически тоже самое, что и прервать его в самом процессе. Просто проверить пока не могу.